Empirical Evidence for Plutchik Theory of Basic Emotions
Plutchik proposed that there are 8 basic emotions, which is arranged in opposite pairs. However, the only empirical tests I could find for his theory were from his own book. Considering it was published in 1991, I feel like there should be more work done to prove or disprove his ideas. Does anyone know of experiments done whose results support or refute his theory?
